# Summing weekly data by month and year

Tags: excel, date, sum, excel-2007

I have an excel 2007 file with data of weekly values for two years. I want to collate this into a cumulative monthly sum, but also bare in mind the year. For example, If I had the following dates:

```
6 Apr 13
13 Apr 13
20 Apr 13
27 Apr 13
4 May 13
.
.
.
.
.
12 Apr 14
19 Apr 14
26 Apr 14
3 May 14
10 May 14
17 May 14
24 May 14
.
.
.
.
14 Feb 15
21 Feb 15
28 Feb 15
7 Mar 15
14 Mar 15
21 Mar 15
28 Mar 15
```

And I wanted to get the summed totals for the following periods:

```
April 2013
May 2013
June 2013
July 2013
.
.
.
.
April 2014
May 2014
June 2014
.
.
.
January 2015
February 2015
March 2015
```

What would be the best way to go about doing so? I was thinking to use Sumifs, but was uncertain how well Month() and Year() play if the function was written like `sumif(...Year(...Month(..)))`.

Comment: Would a pivot table work? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/group-items-in-a-pivottable-report-HP010175903.aspx

Comment: if you'd like functions, use something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((Month(A2:A100)=1)*(Year(A2:A100)=2013)*(B2:B100))` where `B2:B100` range for sum

Comment: I second Brian V. Using built-in functions will often offer better performance than custom solutions. Just make sure if you follow the instructions in Brian's link that you group both the month AND the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in Cells A1:B15, with dates in column A and qaintity to be summed in Column B, you can try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A1:A15)=2)*(YEAR(A1:A15)=2014)*(B1:B15))
```

You can replace "2" with month of your choice and 2014 with desired year. Hope that helps.